# javafx: Gradually add shapes in scene

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, polygon

I have the following code and I am trying to add two more hexagons gradually in the scene(after 1 second each one) when I click the first hexagon. I have tried the Thread.sleep(1000) but the hexagons appear at the same time(when the code is complete).
Can you help me?
Thank you in advanced!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Hexagons extends Application {

Group root;
Scene scene1;
Polygon polygon;
Polygon polygon2;
Polygon polygon3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    root = new Group();
    scene1 = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
    scene1.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.setLayoutY(50);
    polygon2 = new Polygon();
    polygon2.setLayoutY(50);
    polygon3 = new Polygon();
    polygon3.setLayoutY(50);
    polygon.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    polygon.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    polygon2.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    polygon2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    polygon3.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    polygon3.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    root.getChildren().add(polygon);
    Double[] polygonElements;
    Double[] polygon2Elements;
    Double[] polygon3Elements;
    polygonElements = new Double[]{
        100.0, 100.0,
        50.0, 75.0,
        50.0, 25.0,
        100.0, 0.0,
        150.0, 25.0,
        150.0, 75.0};
    polygon2Elements = new Double[]{
        110.0, 100.0,
        60.0, 65.0,
        60.0, 15.0,
        110.0, -10.0,
        160.0, 15.0,
        160.0, 65.0};
    polygon3Elements = new Double[]{
        120.0, 100.0,
        70.0, 65.0,
        70.0, 15.0,
        120.0, -10.0,
        170.0, 15.0,
        170.0, 65.0};
    polygon.getPoints().addAll(polygonElements);
    polygon2.getPoints().addAll(polygon2Elements);
    polygon3.getPoints().addAll(polygon3Elements);
    polygon.setOnMouseClicked((Event event) -> {
        root.getChildren().add(polygon2);
        root.getChildren().add(polygon3);
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [a Transition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html) like this:

```
package com.isp.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Hexagons extends Application
{

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    launch( args );
  }

  @Override public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws IOException
  {
    final Group root = new Group();
    final ObservableList<Node> rootChildren = root.getChildren();

    final Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1000, 1000 );
    scene.setCursor( Cursor.HAND );

    final Polygon polygon = createPolygon(100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 75.0, 50.0, 25.0, 100.0, 0.0, 150.0, 25.0, 150.0, 75.0);


    rootChildren.add( polygon );

    polygon.setOnMouseClicked( ( Event event ) -> {
      final Polygon polygon2 = createPolygon( 110.0, 100.0, 60.0, 65.0, 60.0, 15.0, 110.0, -10.0, 160.0, 15.0, 160.0, 65.0 );
      final Polygon polygon3 = createPolygon( 120.0, 100.0, 70.0, 65.0, 70.0, 15.0, 120.0, -10.0, 170.0, 15.0, 170.0, 65.0 );

      //remove all except first polygon
      rootChildren.retainAll( polygon );

      rootChildren.add( polygon2 );
      rootChildren.add( polygon3 );

      fadeIn( polygon2 );
      fadeIn( polygon3 );
    } );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static void fadeIn( final Node node )
  {
    final FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition( Duration.millis( 200 ) );
    fade.setNode( node );
    fade.setFromValue( 0.0 );
    fade.setToValue( 1.0 );
    fade.play();
  }

  private static Polygon createPolygon( double... points )
  {
    final Polygon polygon = new Polygon( points );
    polygon.setLayoutY( 50 );
    polygon.setFill( Color.TRANSPARENT );
    polygon.setStroke( Color.BLUE );
    return polygon;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Your solution helped me a lot.